# In JMeter, how to capture values from REST POST Request (not the Response)?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

Part of REST POST Request looks like below where I am passing different values for VIN and DEALER_ID:

```
        <ns3:PARAM>
              <ns3:ITEM>VIN</ns3:ITEM>
              <ns3:VALUE xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">${vin}</ns3:VALUE>
        </ns3:PARAM>
        <ns3:PARAM>
              <ns3:ITEM>DEALER_ID</ns3:ITEM>
              <ns3:VALUE xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">${dealer_id}</ns3:VALUE>
        </ns3:PARAM>
```

I need to extract the values from ${vin} and ${dealer_id}, so I can have those on the CSV report with other values I am capturing from Response. I know how to capture values from Response, but don't know how to capture from variables in Request. Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: `vin` is JMeter variable, so it already captured, no?

Answer (score 1):

Just use [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) property

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   sample_variables=vin,dealer_id
   ```
2. Next time you [run JMeter script in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

   ```
   jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
   ```

   `result.jtl` file will have 2 extra columns: `vin` and `dealer_id` holding the values of the respective JMeter Variables for each request

If you want to store the values into a separate file you can use i.e. [Flexible File Writer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin/) plugin